# Makefile Pattern recipe for filename copying and renaming as temporary file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How can I make a pattern recipe for renaming files?

I have a recipe that takes a variable with a list of input files. But those files (Which always have `.irx` extension) must be stripped of the extension and renamed (copied to preserve the original) to uppercase before calling the program that will process them.

An example:

If the variable value is `foo.irx bla.irx` the files should be copied to another place as `FOO` and `BLA` before the actual recipe executes

Haven't tried anything concrete yet, just have been reading makefile docs in search for something that helps me out.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way in GNU Make to "uppercase" a value.  But the shell can do this with the `tr` program.

You can do something like:

```
FILES = foo.irx bla.irx

doit: $(FILES)
        for f in $(^:%.irx=%); do \
            cp $$f.irx $$(echo $$f | tr a-z A-Z); \
        done
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU make you could try:

```
.PHONY: rename
define rename_rule
$1-up := $$(shell echo "$1" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')
rename: $$($1-up)
$$($1-up): $1.irx
    cp $$< $$@
endef
$(foreach i,$(basename $(wildcard *.irx)),$(eval $(call rename_rule,$i)))
```

Demo:

```
$ touch foo.irx bla.irx
$ make rename
cp bla.irx BLA
cp foo.irx FOO
```

Note that the [GNU Make Standard Library](https://gmsl.jgc.org/) by [John Graham-Cumming](https://www.jgc.org/) has `tr`, `uc`, `lc` macros and many amazing others. If you can use it (just download two Makefiles and you're done) a GMSL-based solution could look like:

```
include gmsl
UPS := $(call uc,$(basename $(wildcard *.irx))) # compute uppercase target names
.PHONY: rename
rename: $(UPS)
.SECONDEXPANSION:              # secondary expansion
$(UPS): %: $$(call lc,$$*).irx # static pattern rule
    cp $< $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright... Here's the function to convert a string to uppercase:

```
override alphabet := \
    A-a B-b C-c D-d E-e \
    F-f G-g H-h I-i J-j \
    K-k L-l M-m N-n O-o \
    P-p Q-q R-r S-s T-t \
    U-u V-v W-w X-x Y-y \
    Z-z

override var = $(eval override $(subst #,$$(strip #),$(subst $,$$$$,$1)))

override uppercase = $(call,$(call var,_ret := $1)$(foreach x,$(alphabet),$(call var,_ret := $(subst $(lastword $(subst -, ,$x)),$(firstword $(subst -, ,$x)),$(_ret)))))$(_ret)
```

This is way faster than using `$(shell )` as @RenaudPacalet does in his answer (made a little benchmark processing 10 strings; this code takes ~6ms, while their takes ~56ms).

Here, `var` is a helper function that safely assigns to a variable, without tripping on special characters. `$(call, ...)` is a hack to evaluate the argument and destroy the string it expands to.

And here's how you use it to copy files: (this isn't too different from @RenaudPacalet's answer)

```
.PHONY: all

override define rename_rule =
all: $(call uppercase,$(basename $1))
$(call uppercase,$(basename $1)): $1
    cp $$< $$@
endef
$(foreach f,$(wildcard *.irx),$(eval $(call rename_rule,$f)))
```

Comment: Note that if you really want to do this with pure GNU make, the [GNU Make Standard Library](https://gmsl.jgc.org/) by [John Graham-Cumming](https://www.jgc.org/) may be your friend. It has `tr`, `uc`, `lc` macros and many amazing others.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Just tried it, and if the argument contains `$$`, it fails with an assertion, while my version handles it correctly. I wonder why they didn't just fix it, if they bothered to write an assertion for it. Also apparently both of us silently fail at `#` in input string (fixed it).

Comment: Yes, many macros in GMSL don't support `$` in their arguments. It's a design choice that makes everything simpler, I guess.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I've submitted a bug report. It's not like it's hard to fix, they just need to plug this `var` function in place of some`eval`s.

Comment: Nice. Hope it will pass the tests and will be accepted.

Comment: What is `$(call,` doing? I first thought this to be a syntax error.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Yeah, it is one, but it just expands to nothing instead of raising an actual error. I needed something to discard the string.